# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.UI.Slider[]' to `UnityEngine.UI.Slider'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting error `CS0029` while I was adding a slider to the clicker game to tell how much left you add to buy an item. I am following a YouTube video to learn programming and Unity.

> Assets/scripts/UpgradeManger.cs(20,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.UI.Slider[]' to`UnityEngine.UI.Slider'

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UpgradeManger : MonoBehaviour {
    public Click click;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text itemInfo;
    public float cost;
    public float count = 0;
    public int clickPower;
    public string itemName;
    private float basedCost;
    public Color standard;
    public Color afforable;
    private Slider _slider;

    void start () {
        basedCost = cost;
        _slider = GetComponentsInChildren<Slider>   ();
    }

    void Update (){
        itemInfo.text = itemName + " (" + count + ")" + "\nCost: " + cost + "/nPower: " + clickPower;

        _slider.value = click.gold / cost * 100;
    }

    public void PurchasedUpgrade() {
        if (click.gold >= cost) {
            click.gold -= cost;
            count += 1;
            click.goldperclick += clickPower;
            cost = Mathf.Round (cost * 1.15f);
            basedCost = Mathf.Pow (cost, basedCost = cost);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[00:41] you're using GetComponentsInChildren instead of GetComponentInChildren
[00:41] GetComponentsInChildren returns an array

Comment: Hi there! Is this your own answer to your question? Have you solved the problem? If so, please mark it as such for others to know how to solve it :)

Comment: yes it was me posting the answer sry i didnt mark it new to this site